How to configure Javascript/Typescript formatting settings?
I need to format javascript/typescript code in Eclipse.
Accordingly to that comment I found it can be done using "generic editor" of Eclipse Wild Web Developer plugin either JavaScript Editor of Eclipse WTP JSDT.
I not succeed to get JavaScript Editor of Eclipse WTP JSDT, but managed to get partially what I was need with Generic Editor of WWD by configuring some formatting properties in Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors, e.g. "Insert spaces for tabs" and "Displayed tab width".
Now I need a configuration to add a space after/before round brackets and line wrapping settings, but can't find how I can do it.
Also I red it can be achieved by installing/settled some language server, but have no idea which server and how to bind it with Generic Editor.
Also would be very like to have auto-formatting action on file save.
Any help will by highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

@Mr.Polywhirl too much like Eclipse to leave it..

@Mr.Polywhirl The Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers comes with the same JS and TS support out of the box. In general, please avoid such fanboy comments since they add no value.

See https://github.com/eclipse-wildwebdeveloper/wildwebdeveloper/issues/739#issuecomment-961164622

@howlger would you like convert it to answer with manual what should be done for this specific case?

I'll leave it to others to write a more detailed answer. See also Eclipse help: Non-Ant project builders.

@howlger ok, thank you for significant clue
